# entity framework orderby sum slow performance

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a repository table and add any transaction of products here like this:

```
productID qty:
103 2
103 -1
```

in the view of my products I want to show products order by sum of the qty of products > 0

so I write this :

```
dbContext.tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(n => n.tbl_repository.Sum(x => x.Qty) > 0).ThenByDescending(m => m.ID);
```

but the performance of this is too slow, is there any other way to make it speedy ?

Comment: How many records are in that table? Do the tables have indexes on them? What does the generated SQL from Entity Framework look like?

Comment: @DarrenDavies there is 50000 records in repository table and I indexed productID and qty

Answer (score 0):

You can try leveraging the `GroupBy` method.

First create an (optional) class to hold the results:

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; } // or int, whatever your product id's type is
    public int QuantitySum { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure how your repository is implemented, but try querying the context directly first and see if you get better results:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    var products = db.Products
                     .GroupBy(product => product.ProductID)
                     .Where(productGroup => productGroup.Sum(p => p.Quantity) > 0)
                     .Select(productGroup => new ProductGroup { ProductID = productGroup.Key, QuantitySum = productGroup.Sum(product => product.Quantity) })
                     .OrderByDescending(product => product.ProductID)
                     .ToList();

    // 'products' should be a list of ProductGroup items holding the ID and Sum.
}
```